# LINQ to SQL - Count number of certain item types in each order

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015

For the sake of simplicity of this post, suppose I have data in an Orders table as follows. Here the CustomerId is a foreign key to Customers table. **Question**: How can we write a LINQ Query to find the count of vegetables (V) and the fruits (F) each customer ordered?

**Orders Table**:

```
OrderId | CustomerId | OrderType
1       | 11         | V
2       | 11         | V
3       | 11         | F
4       | 11         | V
5       | 12         | V
6       | 15         | F
7       | 15         | V
8       | 15         | F
```

I can count the number of orders for each customer as follows. `But how about number of Vegetables and number of Fruits in each order?`:

```
var Query1 = from o in Orders
                group o by o.CustomerId
                into grp
                select new {CustomerId = grp.Key, OrderCount = grp.Count()};
```

Comment: *Without lambda expression* requirement seems weird - why wouldn't you use it if it's better fit for the job? Also, your query will be rewritten into Method-based query by compiler anyway, and that will include Lambda Expressions.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I agree with you and have removed the restriction on the usage of Lambda Expression so you can provide that choice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use a subquery:

```
var Query1 = from o in Orders
             group o by o.CustomerId into grp
             select new {
                 CustomerId = grp.Key,
                 OrderCount = grp.Count(),
                 OrderCounts = from g in grp
                               group g by g.OrderType into grp2
                               select new { OrderType = grp2.Key, Count = grp2.Count() }
             };
```

or you can group by both `CustomerId` and `OrderType`:

```
var Query1 = from o in Orders
             group o by new { o.CustomerId, o.OrderType } into grp
             select new {
                 CustomerId = grp.Key.CustomerId,
                 OrderType = grp.Key.OrderType,
                 OrderCount = grp.Count()
             };
```

They will both return the same data but in slightly different form.

Comment: Thank you. Your solutions helped me figure out some other errors I was getting in my other LINQ queries, as well